# 'VCRUNTIME140.dll and MSVCP140.dll' missing when loading QGIS

Tags: qgis, qgis-2.18

I have downloaded QGIS 2.18 on Windows 10 without any problem but and when I start the application, I am getting the below error:

> missing VCRUNTIME140.dll and MSVCP140.dll

Comment: Welcom to GIS SE. As a new user, please take the [Tour]. Questions here should demonstrate some basic research. A google on that error message quickly leads to the Microsoft Visual C++ 2015 Redistributable Runtime, including [this patch](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=52685)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So the answer was relatively easy to find.

I downloaded the [Microsoft Visual C++ Redistributable Runtime](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=48145).  Problem solved!